# Vector cross product axiomatic in a general framework

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I was trying to understand the generalization of he usual vector cross product of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I found a [paper by Rost](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-01/10.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi6s5DK-NboAhVHVhoKHbmUDNsQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw13bNiywKJyTbtqsChQU71_), where he says that it is easy to prove the equivalence between these two definitions.

DEFINITION A. Given a vector space $V$, endowed with a scalar product $\langle,\rangle$, a cross product is a bilinear map $\times : V\times V \rightarrow V$ such that  $$\langle x\times y, z\rangle \text{ is alternating in }x,y,z$$ and $$(x\times y)\times x = \langle x,x\rangle y - \langle x,y\rangle x $$

DEFINITION B. Given a vector space $V$, endowed with a scalar product $\langle,\rangle$, a cross product is a bilinear map $\times : V\times V \rightarrow V$ such that $$\langle x\times y, x\text{ or }y \rangle =0$$ and 
$$\langle x\times y , x\times y\rangle = \langle x,x\rangle \langle y,y\rangle -  \langle x,y\rangle ^2$$

I proved Definition A implies Definition B. But I'm having troubles showing the other way. Assuming Definition B, I proved the first condition of definition A. **However I have no idea how to show condition 2 of definition A**. The only thing that came to my mind was to compute 
$$ \langle (x \times y)\times x,(x \times y)\times x\rangle $$ using the second condition of definition B, but I got nothing clear.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have an identity with $z$ on the left, but not on the right.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\langle(x\times y)\times x - \langle x,x\rangle y + \langle x,y\rangle x,(x\times y)\times x - \langle x,x\rangle y + \langle x,y\rangle x\rangle\\
&=\langle(x\times y)\times x,(x\times y)\times x\rangle-\langle x,x\rangle\langle(x\times y)\times x,y\rangle-\langle x,x\rangle\langle y,(x\times y)\times x\rangle+\langle x,x\rangle^2\langle y,y\rangle-\langle x,x\rangle\langle x,y\rangle^2-\langle x,x\rangle\langle x,y\rangle^2+\langle x,x\rangle\langle x,y\rangle^2\\
&=\langle(x\times y)\times x,(x\times y)\times x\rangle-2\langle x,x\rangle\langle y,(x\times y)\times x\rangle+\langle x,x\rangle^2\langle y,y\rangle-\langle x,x\rangle\langle x,y\rangle^2\\
&=\langle(x\times y),(x\times y)\rangle\langle x,x\rangle+\langle x,x\rangle^2\langle y,y\rangle-\langle x,x\rangle\langle x,y\rangle^2-2\langle x,x\rangle\langle y,(x\times y)\times x\rangle\\
&=2\langle(x\times y),(x\times y)\rangle\langle x,x\rangle-2\langle x,x\rangle\langle (x\times y)\times x,y\rangle\\
&=2\langle x,x\rangle\langle(x\times y),(x\times y)\rangle-2\langle x,x\rangle\langle(x\times y),(x\times y)\rangle=0.
\end{align*}

If $\langle x,x\rangle=0$, we have $x=0$. Also, note that an alternating multilinear map is always skew-symmetric(a fact that is used in the last step).